# why AbstractQueuedSynchronizer didn't make acquire() exclusive?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

the doc said that  `acquire()` is in exclusive mode:

```
// Acquires in exclusive mode, ignoring interrupts.  
public final void acquire(int arg) {
    if (!tryAcquire(arg) && acquireQueued(addWaiter(Node.EXCLUSIVE), arg))
        selfInterrupt();
}
```

Without any restrictions,it first invoke `tryAcquire(arg)`.

If a thread already held the synchronization (acquired and didn't release),other threads can also invoke tryAcquire(arg) without any restrictions and may succeeded in acquiring.

Simply speaking,I mean,why AbstractQueuedSynchronizer doesn't check if a thread has held the synchronization before invoking `tryAcquire(arg)`.

although user can implement `tryAcquire(arg)` ,making sure that the second `tryAcquire(arg)` can not succeed.but I think this is AQS's responsibility.

after thinking a while,I agree that is not good to implement exclusive in acquire(),it's better to implement exclusive in tryAcquire().

Comment: tryAcquire is the one who checks if it can be aquired. From the docs -> "This method should query if the state of the object permits it to be acquired in the exclusive mode, and if so to acquire it.If this method reports failure, the acquire method may queue the thread, if it is not already queued, until it is signalled by a release from some other thread." Acquire must call at least once to the tryAcquire() method, so I don't really get why you say it is not exclusive.

Comment: @aran so is tryAcquire()  guarantee exclusive,not Acquire().you can use Acquire() to implement  a share mode Synchronizer like readlock.but now I realize that there will be some proberm making Acquire exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to make a definitive answer to a "Why"-question, but here is a usecase where I am glad things are the way they are: **Project reactor and virtual threads.**

Assigning resources to threads makes sense when your work-item that accesses the resource runs on one OS-thread and there is no other work-item on that thread.

This may not be the case with programming models that have some notion of m:n threading - your workitem may get switch to another thread, while a different workitem will run on your thread.

Thus, with for example spring-webflux (built on top of reactor) you can synchronize with, for example, a `Semaphore` (which is implemented with the help of `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` but not for example with the builtin `synchronized`-keyword.